# Configure mapFrom expression just once in Automapper for JObject for a common access pattern

Tags: json.net, automapper-5

I am mapping from a JObject to a custom class and it works fine, but i'd rather tell it to do this default type of mapping once instead of having to do a .MapFrom for every property. Most of the source "properties" are just the lowercase underscored version of the Pascal case property names on the destination.

Since JObject doesnt have the values I want as properties, i have to index into them via the MapFrom (I can't use SourceMemberNamingConvention/DestinationMemberNamingConvention). So I want an expression that i can use via something like ForAllOtherMembers to apply this default value retrieval from the JObject but I can't it to work...what options do i have?

I have tried using ResolveUsing method that I would have to also use ConstructedBy method but ResolveUsing returns a void (now? in version 5) so I couldn't do a .ConstructedBy() on it.

Below I am having to do each MapFrom even though they follow the same access pattern:

```
   MapperConfiguration MapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing<BooleanTypeConverter>();
   cfg.CreateMap<JObject, FiscalYear>()
       .ForMember("EmployeeName", 
            options => options.MapFrom(jo => jo["employee_name"]))
       .ForMember("YearName", 
            options => options.MapFrom(jo => jo["year_name"]));
```

UPDATE:
I went ahead and just did it more the manual way and replaced strings with a delegate

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing<BooleanTypeConverter>();

        cfg.CreateMap<JToken, FiscalYear>()
            .Map(d => d.EmployeeName)
            .Map(d => d.Year, "int_year")
            .Map(d => d.Name, "year");
    });
}

public static class MappingExpressionExtensions
{
    private static readonly MatchEvaluator ToSnakeCaseEvaluator = m =>
    {
        string match = m.ToString();
        return "_" + char.ToLower(match[0]) + match.Substring(1);
    };

    public static IMappingExpression<JToken, TDest> Map<TDest, TDestProp>(this IMappingExpression<JToken, TDest> map,
        Expression<Func<TDest, TDestProp>> propertyExpression, string sourceName = null)
    {
        var propertyName = propertyExpression.PropertyName();
        sourceName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceName)
                    ? new Regex("([A-Z])").Replace(propertyName, ToSnakeCaseEvaluator).TrimStart('_')
                    : sourceName;
        var propType = typeof(TDestProp);
        if (propType == typeof(bool))
        {
            // in order for BooleanTypeConverter to work, convert to string and run as a normal mapping
            map.ForMember(propertyExpression.PropertyName(), o => o.MapFrom(jo => jo[sourceName].ToString()));
            return map;
        }

        var isNullableGenericType = propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
        var underlyingType = isNullableGenericType ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType) : propType;
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(underlyingType);

        map.ForMember(propertyName,
            o => o.MapFrom(jo => (isNullableGenericType && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jo[sourceName].ToString()))
                    || (IsNumeric(jo[sourceName]) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jo[sourceName].ToString()))
                        ? 0 : converter.ConvertFrom(jo[sourceName].ToString())));

        return map;
    }

    public static bool IsNumeric(object expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
            return false;

        double number;
        return Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(expression, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out number);
    }
}

public class BooleanTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, bool>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Automapper version compatible with version 4.x
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        switch (context.SourceValue.ToString().ToLower().Trim())
        {
            case "true":
            case "yes":
            case "y":
            case "1":
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    //// Automapper version compatible with version 5.0+
    //public bool Convert(string source, bool destination, ResolutionContext context)
    //{
    //    switch (source.ToLower().Trim())
    //    {
    //        case "true":
    //        case "yes":
    //        case "y":
    //        case "1":
    //            return true;
    //    }

    //    return false;
    //}  

// put this in static class
    public static string PropertyName<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property)
{
  if (property.Body is MemberExpression)
    return ((MemberExpression) property.Body).Member.Name;
  return ((MemberExpression) ((UnaryExpression) property.Body).Operand).Member.Name;
}
}
```

Comment: No automapper gurus out there???  Where is @JimmyBogard when you need him :)

Comment: Regarding `ForAllMembers`, in the most recent version (which I haven't tested), [`IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, out TDestination, TMember>`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IMemberConfigurationExpression.cs) has a property `DestinationMember`.  Could you construct a [`SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm) then capture it in a lambda to map the `MemberInfo.Name` to the snake case name in the `JObject`?

Comment: My understanding is that the strategy is used during deserialization. I am not deserializing from a json string, but mapping from a JsonObject

Comment: Contract resolvers are used during deserialization.  `NamingStrategy` is a lightweight utility class used for mapping property name strings.  You can always just do `new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy().GetPropertyName(someName, false)` to map a string to snake case.  For a mockup see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oa1nR2.  (It's a mockup because dotnetfiddle won't load the correct versions of Json.NET or Automapper.)